# Div not always floating right

Tags: html, css

I'm currently having trouble with my css:

```
.text {
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: #ffffff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffffff 0%, #ebebeb 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(100%, #ebebeb));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffffff 0%, #ebebeb 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffffff 0%, #ebebeb 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffffff 0%, #ebebeb 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ffffff 0%, #ebebeb 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ebebeb', GradientType=1 );
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,29,50,0.5);
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.side {
    width: 20%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 7px;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: #ffffff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffffff 0%, #ebebeb 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(100%, #ebebeb));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffffff 0%, #ebebeb 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffffff 0%, #ebebeb 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffffff 0%, #ebebeb 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ffffff 0%, #ebebeb 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ebebeb', GradientType=1 );
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,29,50,0.5);
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

(See it working at http://jsfiddle.net/8L5Tf/)

As you can see at JSFiddle my second sidebar touches the other, but I want it to float beneath the other one, how can I fix this?

Comment: In that case please mark as answer.  :)  Happy to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `clear: right;` on the `.side` class: http://jsfiddle.net/8L5Tf/1/

Floats can be tricky though, so consider putting them both in one div, as Richard said in his comment.  It might just end up being easier to manage.

Comment: Nice solution @Dan. I deleted my comment, and added it as a more detailed answer instead.

Comment: I actually prefer your answer in the event that the user doesn't have a specific reason for doing this my way.  Have an upvote.

Comment: could also move text above the sidebars and clear:both on that.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a container div;

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="side">
        <div>
            Text...
        </div>
        <div>
            Text ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        Text text
    </div>
</div>
```

(and then update your CSS so that the cosmetic styling that was applied to `.side` is applied to `.side > div`.)

See http://jsfiddle.net/8L5Tf/3/